# no module named 'Seaborn' after installed it -- (Mac OS) Jupyter lab

Tags: python, macos

Python version 3.10.8. I used the Mac terminal to install seaborn. Still get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'` in the Jupyter lab. Restart both Jupyter lab and the computer several times and not working.

```
pip 22.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn-0.11.2-py3.10.egg (0.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from seaborn) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from seaborn) (1.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from seaborn) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from seaborn) (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (9.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (4.37.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2022.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.16.0)
```

Comment: Are you sure jupyter-lab runs the same Python installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  jupyter notebook is not running from the same environment. I would suggest you install the package from notebook.

In notebook cell run this:

```
%pip install seaborn
```

This will install `seaborn` in the whatever environment you are using.